# Select first element in div

Tags: html, css, styles

Is it possible to address the first element in a div when you don't know what the first element is.

I have for example two different divs

```
<div class="templateOne">
 <h1>Header 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="templateOne">
 <h2>Header 2</h2>
</div>
```

That I can then say

```
.templateOne > * {
 margin-top: 0em;
}
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use adress the first child element, you can use the `:first-child` or the `:nth-child(1)` pseudo-selector.

```css
.templateOne :first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="templateOne">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <p>Content 1</p>
</div>

<div class="templateOne">
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
```

If you want to address only the first element with a specific class name you can use `:first-of-type` or `nth-of-type(1)`:

```css
.templateOne:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="templateOne">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <p>Content 1</p>
</div>

<div class="templateOne">
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

* [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

[:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```css
.templateOne > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0em;
}
```

Comment: `.templateOne :first-child` would be sufficient as selector.